# best funktion to rotate to mouse position unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

**I watched a tutorial and he did it like this:**

```
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public Camera cam;

Vector2 movement;
Vector2 mousePos;

void Update()
{
    mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y ,lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
    rb.rotation = angle;
}
```

**but I thought i could do it in a simpler way:**

```
Vector3 mousePosition;

void Update()
{
    mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    Vector2 direction = mousePosition - transform.position;

    transform.up = direction;
}
```

**It works but i thought "why would he do it in such a complicated way? is it more efficient ore something?" and exactly this is the question i cant get out of my head.**

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! your code is of course in `c#`

Answer (score 1):

No reason to use the `FixedUpdate` for the camera update. Actually it is adviced to use the `LateUpdate()` because it tracks objects that might have moved inside Update`. Check the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html).

Regarding the eficiency, I would say your way is more efficient, but to be sure I would check setting some timers and check which way is more efficient with some useless `for`s just for the sake of the efficiency study, like for example:

measurement1:

```
var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i<1000000; i++) {
    Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y ,lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
    rb.rotation = angle;
}
watch.Stop();
Debug.LogError($"elapsed: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
```

measurement2:

```
var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i<1000000; i++) {
    mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector2 direction = mousePosition - transform.position;
    transform.up = direction;
}
watch.Stop();
Debug.LogError($"elapsed: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
```